# Angular - Dynamic form - Access field values

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-forms

I need to populate some form fields with an API response, after changing the value of specific fields. My problem is that I do not know how to listen to that change, or how to access their values so as to send a proper request body. This always results in undefined values for the fields in question. The form is dynamically generated, so there isn't any actual HTML.

Below are the coding files I believe are responsible for this behavior.

**configure-point-api.service.ts**

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as Configuration from '../../../../../../../configuration/config';
import { IConfigurePoint } from '../components/configure-point.interface';
import { IPointInfo } from '../../../check/point/components/point.interface';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { toBool } from 'src/shared/toBool';
import { ConfigurePointStateService } from '../state/configure-point-state.service';
import { FieldConfig } from 'src/shared/components/dynamic-form/field.interface';
import { fields } from '../components/configure-point.fields';

const config = Configuration;

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurePointApiService {
  configurePointStateSub: Subscription;
  fields: FieldConfig[] = fields;
  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private configurePointStateService: ConfigurePointStateService
  ) {}

  getPoints(): Observable<IConfigurePoint> {
    return this.http.post<IPointInfo>(`${config.apiV1Url}/${config.getPointConfig}`, {
      type: 10,
      panel: 0,
      zone: 0,
      loop: 1,
      index: 1,
      size: 0,
      extra: 0,
      string1: '',
      string2: '',
      string3: '',
      string4: '',
    })
    .pipe(map((response: IPointInfo) => {
      
      this.configurePointStateService.setConfigurePointData(response);
      return {
        loop: Number(response.loop),
        address: Number(response.address),
        name: response.name,
        zone: Number(response.zone),
        point_type: Number(response.point_type),
        luminary_model: Number(response.luminary_model),
        registered: toBool(response.registered)
      } as IConfigurePoint;
    }));
  }

  getPoint(res: IPointInfo): Observable<IConfigurePoint> {
    return this.http.post<IPointInfo>(`${config.apiV1Url}/${config.getPointConfig}`, {
      type: 10,
      panel: 0,
      zone: 0,
      loop: res.loop,
      index: res.address,
      size: 0,
      extra: 0,
      string1: '',
      string2: '',
      string3: '',
      string4: '',
    })
    .pipe(map((res: IPointInfo) => {
      return {
        loop: Number(res.loop),
        address: Number(res.address),
        name: res.name,
        zone: Number(res.zone),
        point_type: Number(res.point_type),
        luminary_model: Number(res.luminary_model),
        registered: toBool(res.registered)
      } as IConfigurePoint;
    }));
  }

  setConfigurePoint(req: IConfigurePoint): Observable<IPointInfo> {
    return this.http.post<IPointInfo>(`${config.apiV1Url}/${config.setPointConfig}`, {
      panel: 0,
      loop: Number(req.loop),
      address: Number(req.address),
      name: req.name,
      zone: Number(req.zone),
      point_type: Number(req.point_type),
      luminary_model: Number(req.luminary_model),
      registered: req.registered === true ? 1 : 0,
    });
  }
}
```

`getPoints()` is initialized on load, and the form is correctly populated with the API response.

`getPoint(arg)` is called on *(change)* with a new request to finally re-populate the form with the new response.

`setConfigurePoint(arg)` is called on *(submit)* to register a new device.

I would like to stress that `getPoints()` and `setConfigurePoint(arg)` are working as they should.

**configure-point-container.component.ts**

```
import { FieldConfig } from 'src/shared/components/dynamic-form/field.interface';
import { IPointInfo } from '../../../check/point/components/point.interface';
import { IConfigurePoint } from '../components/configure-point.interface';
import { ConfigurePointFacadeService } from '../configure-point-facade.service';
import { fields } from '../components/configure-point.fields';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'configure-point-container',
  templateUrl: 'configure-point-container.component.html',
})
export class ConfigurePointContainerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  configurePoints: IConfigurePoint;
  configurePointsSub: Subscription;
  point: IConfigurePoint;
  configurePointDataSub: Subscription;
  setConfigurePointSub: Subscription;
  fields: FieldConfig[] = fields;  
  req: IPointInfo;
  
  constructor(private ConfigurePointFacade: ConfigurePointFacadeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configurePointsSubscribe();
  }
  
  configurePointsSubscribe() {
    this.configurePointsSub = 
      this.ConfigurePointFacade.getConfigurePoints().subscribe(
        (configurePoints: IConfigurePoint) => {
          this.configurePoints = configurePoints;
          console.log(this.configurePoints);
        }
      );
  }

  getPointData(res: IPointInfo) {
    this.configurePointDataSub = this.ConfigurePointFacade.getPoint(res)
      .subscribe((data: IConfigurePoint) => {
        this.point = data;
        console.log(this.point); 
    });
  }

  setConfigurePoint(req: IConfigurePoint): void {
    this.setConfigurePointSub =
      this.ConfigurePointFacade.setConfigurePoint(req).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.configurePointsSub) {
      this.configurePointsSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.configurePointDataSub) {
      this.configurePointDataSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.setConfigurePointSub) {
      this.setConfigurePointSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Pointing out that all interfaces have been checked. In the api-service file, on value change, when trying to *POST* the body, the key *index*'s value (*res.address*) should be equal to the value of the address field, and comes from a different interface.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I could tackle this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Comment: `My problem is that I do not know how to listen to that change` form controls have a `valueChange` property, which is an `EventEmitter` you can subscribe to. This will catch any change in your field and enable you to react upon.

Comment: @MikeS. It is a quite large project that fell onto me midway through, so once I find some time in the next couple of days I will reproduce a part of it. I can see your point, so thank you for this indication and definitely thank you for your suggestion. I am currently still looking into it.